# Shell script file name format

Tags: scripting, shell, files, ksh

What does the following shell script mean?
This is ksh and npfile is also a variable that contains a file name.

```
fileName=${npFile##/*/}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It strips the base off of the path to the file.  In variable expansion, ## means "take the thing to my right, treat it as a pattern, and delete the longest match of it in the variable to my left."

In this case the pattern is /*/, so the longest match of that in a variable which included a path and filename would be the path.  Deleting it would leave only the filename.

It appears to be a variable-expansion-only way of writing this:

```
filename=`basename $npFile`
```

Answer (score 1):

That trims "/*/" (everything from the first slash to the last slash) from the beginning of the string.

So if npFile="/path/to/file" - fineName would become "file"